# NatTable mix of fixed width column and on resizable filling remaining space

Tags: java, swt, nattable, nebula

How to make a Nebula NatTable with mix of fixed columns and one remaining filling up all the available vertical space and where, crucially, the fixed width column cold be user resized?

Visual example:

```
+-----------------------------------------+-------+-------+
|     ...fills available vert space...    | 100px | 100px |
```

User resizes middle column by pushing border between columns 0 and 1 to the left:

```
+---------------------------------------+----------+-------+
|     ...fills available vert space...  |   120px  | 100px |
```

User resizes 3rd column by pushing border between columns 1 and 2 to the left:

```
+------------------------------------+----------+----------+
|   ...fills available vert space... |   120px  |   120px  |
```

I got very close with this code:

```
    IRowDataProvider<String> bodyDataProvider = ...;
    DataLayer bodyDataLayer = new DataLayer(bodyDataProvider);
    SelectionLayer selectionLayer = new SelectionLayer(bodyDataLayer, false);
    ViewportLayer viewportLayer = new ViewportLayer(selectionLayer);

    bodyDataLayer.setColumnPercentageSizing(0, true);
    bodyDataLayer.setColumnPositionResizable(0, true);

    bodyDataLayer.setColumnWidthByPosition(1, 100);
    bodyDataLayer.setColumnPositionResizable(1, true);

    bodyDataLayer.setColumnWidthByPosition(2, 100);
    bodyDataLayer.setColumnPositionResizable(2, true);
```

It does visually what was intended, it reacts on container (Shell) resizing as intended too; that is fixed columns remain 100px and only the first column resizes. So far good. But there is a problem: something bad happens to the inter-column resizing. I just reacts weirdly. Resizing handler (header border) between columns 0 and 1 does not do anything, only appears resizing but resizing is not executed; resizing handler between columns 1 and 2 reacts but only column 1 can be effectively resized, column 2 always retains its size, whatever you do.

*Example of the bad behaviour: you want to resize column 2 (3rd column), to make it larger; you grab the border between column 1 and 2, dragging the border to the **left** with intention to make column 2 larger by effectively pushing column 1 to the left too. But instead column 2 stays the same while column 1 shrinks!*

**UPDATE**

My question is how to implement desired behaviour. What and where I need to set or re-implement? Customize `SizeConfig`? Methods in there sounds promising: `calculatePercentages()` and `calculateAvailableSpace()`. Who and when is calling them? How to catch column resize event? DO I need to set listener somewhere? How I can make NatTable to use a customized `SizeConfig`?
Am I on the right track?

Comment: I've created a bug report for the (side) issue mentioned: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=516625. I thing I figured out why NatTable behaves so strangely with the default setup and why is first column from my example effectively unresizable using vanilla ColumnResizeCommandHandler.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself. In the end it wasn't that hard.
All that has to be done is to register a customized `ColumnResizeCommand` handler and implement it.

To the NatTable creation block of code add:

```
bodyDataLayer.registerCommandHandler(
     new BetweenColumnResizeCommandHandler(bodyDataLayer));
```

*It can be anywhere, I have it just after columns are defined*

This overrides the default `BodyDataLayer` setting which is set to default class `ColumnResizeCommandHandler` in method . The register is a map based so it can be repeatedly overridden. The register maps classes command classes (representing events) to action (handlers) for given layer (terminal consumer of the event/command).

Here is my implementation of `BetweenColumnResizeCommandHandler` class:

```
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.command.AbstractLayerCommandHandler;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.DataLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.resize.command.ColumnResizeCommand;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.resize.command.ColumnResizeCommandHandler;

/**
 * Customised version of {@link ColumnResizeCommandHandler}.
 * 
 * It implements "between" resizing mode, that is border is moved between two
 * adjacent column only, having no effects on any other columns; that is any
 * gain in size of the left side column is lost in size for right side column
 * and vice versa.
 * 
 * @author Espinosa
 */
public class BetweenColumnResizeCommandHandler extends AbstractLayerCommandHandler<ColumnResizeCommand> {

    private final DataLayer dataLayer;

    public BetweenColumnResizeCommandHandler(DataLayer dataLayer) {
        this.dataLayer = dataLayer;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<ColumnResizeCommand> getCommandClass() {
        return ColumnResizeCommand.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean doCommand(ColumnResizeCommand command) {
        int leftSideColumn = command.getColumnPosition();
        int rightSideColumn = leftSideColumn + 1;

        int oldLeftSideColumnWidth = this.dataLayer.getColumnWidthByPosition(leftSideColumn);
        int newLeftSideColumnWidth = command.getNewColumnWidth();
        int dragWidth = newLeftSideColumnWidth - oldLeftSideColumnWidth;  
        // dragWidth has to be re-calculated back because it is lost in ColumnResizeCommandHandler :( 

        int oldRightSideColumnWidth = this.dataLayer.getColumnWidthByPosition(rightSideColumn);
        int newRightSideColumnWidth = oldRightSideColumnWidth - dragWidth;

        this.dataLayer.setColumnWidthByPosition(leftSideColumn, newLeftSideColumnWidth);
        if (rightSideColumn < this.dataLayer.getColumnCount()) {
            this.dataLayer.setColumnWidthByPosition(rightSideColumn, newRightSideColumnWidth);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

..and it does EXACTLY what I want, as per example above.

Comment: That would have been exactly my answer. :)

Comment: @Dirk I am not sure if my solution would work if columns rearranged, order change or column is hidden, would still be `rightSideColumn = leftSideColumn + 1` Also I am not sure how to correctly use `GUIHelper.convertVerticalDpiToPixel()`. Please feel free to review, comment, improve!

Comment: As you register your IDragMode on the DataLayer and the DataLayer is the bottom most layer in the layer stack, it does not know about hidden or re-arranged columns. And in the example above I don't see the usage of `GUIHelper.convertVerticalDpiToPixel()`. NatTable is using it internally in `ColumnResizeDragMode` to deal with upscaled display resolutions to calculate the pixel values out of the DPI value. Not sure what you need it for.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to think from right to left. But the resizing is implemented from left to right. So if you take the border between column 1 and 2 you are resizing column 1, not column 2. The direction does not matter.

That is the similar behavior than in well known spreadsheet applications. Taking the handle between borders will resize the column to the left, not the right.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I have just tested it with LibreOffice Calc and SWT Tree, and they both on dragging border to the left they *move* left column to the right while shrinking the left column. Also in my limited experience with spreadsheets all columns are in fact fixed type columns, so the analogy is limited. Anyway, that is not the main point. Please what should I do to implement my desired behaviour?